# getspeed() method is coming innacurate

Tags: android, service, gps

I used getspeed method in service and it is giving me wrong outputs.

```
speed = location.getSpeed();
```

I tested it well and my speed was around 100 km/hr  and get speed method was giving value 25 (value of speed variable was 25) . Why is it so? And yes now my phone is lying still on table and it is giving value as 1.75 . I expected 0 at this time. Why this unknown behavior?

Comment: And you are thinking that we just magically know the exact source of your issue by looking at one line of code?

Comment: i guess that this one  line is giving me speed nothing magical here. I am not a magician btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

value 25 is in meters per second, so by converting it to km/hr we will get:

```
25(m/s) * 3600seconds (1 hour) / 1000 (meters) = 90 km/hr
```

that is about your 100 km/hr value. As for lying device on the table, that giving you 1.75 m/s - it's some error, that gps module giving you. It also depends on what device you have. Everything has vulnerability, so don't be perfectionist :)

Comment: You can check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767151/how-to-get-the-most-accurate-possible-speed-from-gps-in-android for example. Also it depends on your device. If it has not so good GPS module, it will always give you some error.