# Google glass- GDK app getSpeed() returns 0.0

Tags: android, gps, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to display the speed of the user on google glass live card.
I am able to get latitude and longitude,But getSpeed() always returns 0.0. I have checked similar questions on SO ,but of no help.

Here is my Code

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        boolean isEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
        if (isEnabled) {
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        if (location != null) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Start_service.this.getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        // lat,lng, your current location
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            lati= location.getLatitude();
            longi=location.getLongitude();
            speed=location.getSpeed();
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Location providers don't guarantee to provide the speed value.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) You can only getSpeed from the provider that calls setSpeed. You can set the Criteria variable to indicate that you need the speed value.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
```

Or you might consider to calculate it yourself. See [why getSpeed() always return 0 on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811920/why-getspeed-always-return-0-on-android).

Also, use hasSpeed() to check if a speed is available.

Comment: Even if I set the criteria.. speed returns 0..Any clues?

Comment: well, i'm not sure. probably GDK's bug. It's still beta so please be patient.